Why does Voice Control send F4 when asked to press the End key?
I'm on a team that builds out a React design system. One of the things we routinely do is test our components using various input devices, one of them being MacOS's Voice Control feature.
When asking Voice Control to "press the end key", it sends the "F4" key. Asking to "press the home key" sends "Home" as I would expect.
Turns out asking "press the F4 key" actually sends the "End" key, so these are actually swapped. Perhaps a bug in MacOS?
I'm reading these in the browser in a keydown event, the e.code property if that's helpful. You can check what it does on your machine on this site: https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html
